# Search for files with name contains specific numbers

Tags: c#, search

I have thousands of files with various directories. All filenames contain numbers like (abc 2354 , nfg 8239 sdf , abc 23 , qwe 23) and so on.
I want to search for files whose names contain (23) only.

I’ve tried many search patterns but all the same result. This is my code :

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathh, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(p => p.Contains(searchword));
foreach (string file in files)
    if (File.Exists(file))
        listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
```

So the result must be (abc 23 , qwe 23) only, but it returns with all names which contain 23 like (abc 2354 , nfg 8239 sdf , abc 23 , qwe 23) !!

Comment: Read on "C# natural sort" - that should give you code to filter values wherever the numbers are... Otherwise someone will write regex for you.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No, the filenames are variety and numbers are also variety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try a more minimal and complete example.  Below I output to console, but you can easily change it back to fit your need.

The big idea is that I bring in Regex to avoid hits where the word is surrounded by a decimal character.

```
var path = @"some path here";
var searchWord = "23";

var regex = new Regex($@"[^0-9]{searchWord}[^0-9]");

var files = 
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(p => regex.Match(p).Success);

foreach (string file in files) {
    if (File.Exists(file)) {
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }
}
```

This assumes a little bit of a looser requirement.  The number 23 can't be ebedded within a larger number.  If you really don't want another number to appear anywhere in the path, try this regex:

```
var regex = new Regex($@"^[^0-9]*{searchWord}[^0-9]+$");
```

And if you want this restriction at the file level, but not at the path level, change your linq where statement to the following:

```
.Where(p => regex.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p)).Success);
```

Comment: Thanks, First solution worked as i want. Second one doesn't work.